# Which software can simulate room reverb and response?

Tags: software, impulse-response, room-treatment

I would like to roughly estimate the behaviour of my living room as it is now and with some sound absorbing elements, such as bass traps, Helmholtz panels and/or resonators, skyline diffusers.

The room is a normal U-shaped, common for the ground floors that include a kitchen in one of the ends , entrance in the middle and living room in the other end.

What software would allow me to roughly estimate the impulse response with and without treatment?

Free software is preferred, even if it requires tools like Matlab or Mathematica and similar.

Comment: By "estimate", do you mean a software with which you can measure the room impulse response? For that I recommend [Room EQ Wizard](https://www.roomeqwizard.com/). It has a detailed step-by-step guide on how to perform the measurement. If instead you mean a software where you enter the basic characteristics of your room so that it computes an estimation of its acoustics—I don't know of anything that works reliantly.

Comment: @SteffenRummel I know REW. I mean simulation in advance, basically like REW room simulator, but in 3D, non-rectangular rooms, and with the ability to place absorbers or traps arbitrarily, like in corners, walls (not the whole wall), ...

Comment: The reason a software like you describe is unlikely to give reliant results is the huge number of factors that play into room acoustics and their interdependence. At the very least, you should perform one measurement, either in the treated room or before the acoustic treatment. From that and with the knowledge of the absorption coefficients and surface areas of the absorbers in play, you can make educated guesses regarding their effect on the RT60. The effect of acoustic elements on the RIR is nearly impossible to estimate, even when using tuned absorbers.

Comment: @SteffenRummel I was discarding REW because it offers only generic reflection coefficients, not frequency dependent, and because it cannot simulate U-shaped rooms. But if that is your opinion, better to combine all these information (from REW on, mentioning the room simulator) in an answer that I can accept in few days. I just found http://ease.afmg.eu/index.php/features.html but it's beyond the budget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i-Simpa, An Open Source software for 3D sound propagation modelling
http://i-simpa.ifsttar.fr/
seems to support arbitrary geometry (as your U-shaped room) and comprehensive materials :

> Material properties
>
> Define acoustic parameters by frequency band: absorption, transmission
>   loss, scattering, scattering reflection law. Add material information
>   (description, physical parameters...).